# Android Backup Application File of old App

Tags: android, apk, backup

So I have this old-ish Android app running on my Pixel Android 12 phone, the app was last updated on 2018 and it clearly uses old API or whatever and the built-in backup functions are obsolete.
It offers option to export its DB to a folder but it can only access /data/user/0/com/cooly.OilChangeSchedulePro/ folder (yes, im giving out the app name, who cars)

My question is how the heck I can take that file out of my phone? I do not have it rooted (and rooting will make it wipe, so no sense)..

1. tried using adb run-as package but then the package is not debuggable.
2. tried to make the package debuggable by changing Manifest and repacking, but i cannot upgrade the app with my custom package.
3. tried adb backup com.cooloy.OilChangeSchedulePro and it gets an empty backup, nothing inside.

Any other way I can access that folder on my phone and copy out my DB to be restored on other phone?

Regards

Comment: Questions about topics other than development or programming, but related to Android, are not on-topic for Stack Overflow, but **may** be on-topic at https://android.stackexchange.com (and you're more likely to get a good answer there). Please review [the guidelines for posting in that community](//android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before posting there to ensure that your question is on-topic.

Comment: Thank you very much, didnt know that, good tip, I'll mark this as answered with that hint and move from there.